# Returning a null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, subsonic

```
 public void SchemeUpdate(int SchemeID, int InsurerID, string Name, string Description)
        {
            Health_Scheme_System.Scheme updscheme = Scheme.Find(x => x.SchemeID == SchemeID).FirstOrDefault();

            //updscheme.SchemeID = SchemeID;
            //updscheme.InsurerID = InsurerID;
            updscheme.Name = Name;
            updscheme.Description = Description;                             
            updscheme.Save();
}


Calling the method


  //Converting to integer and date
                    int SchemeID;
                    int.TryParse(txtSchemeID.Text, out SchemeID);

                    int insurerID;
                    int.TryParse(txtInsurerID.Text, out insurerID);


                    //Getting the parameters from the method
                    DataAccess updscheme = new DataAccess();
                    //DataAccess updrates = new DataAccess();
                    updscheme.SchemeUpdate(SchemeID, insurerID, txtName.Text, txtDescription.Text);
                    //updrates.RatesUpdate(SchemeID, txtRates.Text);

                    //Binding the gridView to display the updates
                    txtSchemeID.Visible = false;
                    txtInsurerID.Visible = false;
                    gvSchemeMain.DataSource = ds.GetRates();
                    gvSchemeMain.DataBind();
```

I think the problems is with the parameters..

Comment: Can you give more detail? Where in the code do you get the exception?

Comment: The only method in the code you posted, that returns something is `ds.GetRates();`, Can we get a quick peek at that methods source?

Comment: Maybe updscheme == null after calling Scheme.Find

Comment: Sry guys if I made any confussion but I am new with these concepts.. Here is the part which is getting the error.

updscheme.Name = Name;
            updscheme.Description = Description;                             
            updscheme.Save();

Comment: @stecya `.FirstOrDefault()` should (might) take care of that.

Comment: maybe it can be a problem with the parameters???

Comment: @The Scrum Meister - No it wouldn't. FirstOrDefault return object or null. If it is null than   updscheme.Name will crash with NullReferenceException

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment it looks like this line:

```
Health_Scheme_System.Scheme updscheme = Scheme.Find(x => x.SchemeID == SchemeID).FirstOrDefault();
```

is not returning anything. In other words, there is no Scheme with an ID of whatever you're using.

Can you manually check in the database for a `Scheme` and get it's ID value. You can then test the above code by passing that value into the SchemeID parameter.

Comment: Infact in the database it is saving mate. Thanks alot for your help jason :) Thanks again to everyone!!